# css :nth-child(x+x):nth-child(x+x) and margins

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to archive something that might not be possible.

I have 30 (6 rows x 5 columns) items which all have margin-right:5px. This starts out all nice.

From item 14 i need to give a margin:0 on every 6th item :nth-child(x+x) so it all fits nicely.

Is this at all possible, i tried some combinations with but could not get it to work.

```
:nth-child(n+x):nth-child(-n+x) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

So, in a nutshell this is what i need:

1-13 5px,
14 has 0,
15-19 5px,
20 has 0,
21-25 5px,
26 has 0,
and so on, i would like it to be infinite because there will be an ajax load more function.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try `:nth-child(6n + 14) { margin: 0; }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what yuo need:

```
item {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
item:nth-child(6n+14) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you mister :) Awesome!

Comment: @DreadyE if this is good for you, please accept the answer and up-vote it :)